# Using scholarly to get data from Google Scholar gives "Cannot Fetch from Google Scholar"

Tags: python, google-scholar

I'm trying to get data from Google Scholar

```
from scholarly import scholarly

search_query = scholarly.search_author('Albert Einstein')
author = next(search_query).fill()
```

and the output that I obtain is:

```
MaxTriesExceededException: Cannot Fetch from Google Scholar.
```

Any idea of what it's going wrong?

I'm using scholarly == 1.7.6 and I'm using a VPN so it shouldn't be an IP problem.

Comment: What is the version of your ```scholarly```?

Comment: The last one, 1.7.6.

Comment: I think this is because Google Scholar is blocking ```scholarly```, so you need to set up your own proxy with ```ProxyGenerator``` in ```scholarly```.

Comment: Sadly doesn't solve the problem. After a while (around 3 min) it outputs the same: "Cannot Fetch from Google Scholar."

Comment: In case anybody is going through the same issue, "pip install fake-useragent --upgrade" solves the problem.